# beginner: django serializers.serialize

Tags: python, django

Disclaimer: I am new to django but have coded in Drupal

I need to return JSON data to my webpage. In my code,

```
x    = serializers.serialize('json', Temp.objects.all())
```

returns

```
[{"pk": 1, "model": "wizard.temp", "fields": {"p": "message", "k": null, "m": null, "v": "PLEASE WAIT -- Counting and enumerating your images..."}}]'
```

How do I remove the leading and trailing brackets -- that is, the [ and ] ?

It seems only Firefox understands data[0]['pk'], so I'd like to instead do data['pk'].

Comment: And what happens when more than one model is returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to be serializing only one instance of `Temp`. For example, to serialize only the first instance:

```
serializers.serialize('json', Temp.objects.all()[0])
```

Comment: Yes, perfect! This table only has one row. Otherwise, I was going to use: x = serializers.serialize('json', Temp.objects.all())[1:-1]